# Creating excel file using Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing an application where I am using SQLite database and need to  export the data to a .xlsx file programmatically. Googled it out. Do we have any way that we can do it with Titanium Appcelerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to create the excel file on the device?

A few alternative solutions are:

1. send the data to a server, and generate the excel file overthere
2. create a `.csv` export of your `sqlite data`, and import that csv into excel

Comment: Yes, I know other options can be used. But, that is a client requirement. I am finding the solutions, if nothing works, I will need to use any of the methods as you mentioned here. But, it is good if I can implement the actual functionality.

Comment: Is he going to view the excel file on his device?  Is offline functionality involved? Or what is his use case?

Comment: Yes, he is going to save that excel file on the device. The offline functionality is there. There will be some tables where the data is being stored. He should be able to export the data into an excel file and should be able to mail it if it needs. That's the use case.

Comment: Are you using ArrowDB too? Because it's easy to send an email from within arrowDB. (but then you have to send the data to the server). Imho if not really required, I would not generate an excel on the device.

Comment: Not using ArrowDB. Well, I convinced that client to export the data in CSV though! ;)